# Add javax.websocket to Intellij IDEA project?

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, shared-libraries

I want to add javax.websocket to an Intellij IDEA project to support creating a web socket client. How can I do this? From the screen shot below you can see the project is finding javax.net.ssl, but not javax.websocket:

[image]

I notice that if I go to Project/Settings/Libraries and click the green + sign, then choose Maven, I get a "download" from Maven repository option, which upon searching for "websocket" comes up with dozens of choices as shown below:

[image]

Is this the right procedure to use? If so, which of these dozens of choices should I pick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comes late, but... the easiest way to do so is to add `javax.websocket-api.jar` to your project as a *provided* library. You can add this jar manually, or simply use maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or even better gradle:

```
'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.0'
```

Latest version in time of writing this answer is 1.1.